# How can i change map size?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-maps

I have a map on my react project. But i cant change size of it. I tried add css but its not working i think i used wrong css. My sandbox for you see : https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-cookies-89ez0?file=/src/components/GoogleMap.js

What i tried :

I wrap map with a div (mapSection className) and gave it to max-height and max-width. It didnt work.
I gave height-width manually like 300-500px but didnt work too. What should i do ? Thanks for reply! I want to make it smaller.

Comment: Edit: your Sandbox does not seem to be workign properly. you probably are loading a map in a `iframe` or  something like that, you would need to change the size of that element, or maybe play with the settings in the Google Map plugin/dashboard

Comment: @avia Thanks for response! I deleted my api key from there. Maybe thats why its not working. I didnt put my map in iframe . I just have map component and its in a div. But map coming from a google-maps-react library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `position` property for the `mapSection` class to relative

```
.mapSection {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Because the map container has an `absolute` value

You can read more about this property here:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp ,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position